# Transition on menu open/close

Tags: css, css-transitions

I create [this very simple layout](https://codesandbox.io/s/menu-l9jf7) in which there are a button that user can click to open and close the menu.

I try to add a CSS transition when menu is opening/closing but it seems not to work.

This is the div that should be use the transition:

```
<div className={`${isMenuOpen ? "w4" : "w-0"} bg-yellow transition`} />

.transition {
  transition: all 1.5s ease;
}
```

Why?

Comment: Can you post the code snippet that you wrote for your CSS transition?

Comment: @Subbu Sure! I added the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `.w-0` doesn't have a defined `width`. The transition property needs an initial value to transition *from*.

Just add this to your CSS file:

```
.w-0 {
  width: 0;
}
```